# How to implement a timed wait around a blocking call?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, timeout, boost-thread

So, the situation is this.  I've got a C++ library that is doing some interprocess communication, with a `wait()` function that blocks and waits for an incoming message.  The difficulty is that I need a *timed* wait, which will return with a status value if no message is received in a specified amount of time.

The most elegant solution is probably to rewrite the library to add a timed wait to its API, but for the sake of this question I'll assume it's not feasible.  (In actuality, it looks difficult, so I want to know what the other option is.)

Here's how I'd do this with a busy wait loop, in pseudocode:

```
while(message == false && current_time - start_time < timeout)
{
  if (Listener.new_message()) then message = true;
}
```

I don't want a busy wait that eats processor cycles, though.  And I also don't want to just add a `sleep()` call in the loop to avoid processor load, as that means slower response.  I want something that does this with a proper sort of blocks and interrupts.  If the better solution involves threading (which seems likely), we're already using `boost::thread`, so I'd prefer to use that.

I'm posting this question because this seems like the sort of situation that would have a clear "best practices" right answer, since it's a pretty common pattern.  What's the right way to do it?

**Edit to add:** A large part of my concern here is that this is in a spot in the program that's both performance-critical and critical to avoid race conditions or memory leaks.  Thus, while "use two threads and a timer" is helpful advice, I'm still left trying to figure out how to actually implement that in a safe and correct way, and I can easily see myself making newbie mistakes in the code that I don't even know I've made.  Thus, some actual example code would be really appreciated!

Also, I have a concern about the multiple-threads solution: If I use the "put the blocking call in a second thread and do a timed-wait on that thread" method, what happens to that second thread if the blocked call never returns?  I know that the timed-wait in the first thread will return and I'll see that no answer has happened and go on with things, but have I then "leaked" a thread that will sit around in a blocked state forever?  Is there any way to avoid that?  (Is there any way to avoid that and avoid leaking the second thread's memory?)  A complete solution to what I need would need to avoid having leaks if the blocking call doesn't return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sigaction(2)` and `alarm(2)`, which are both POSIX.  You set a callback action for the timeout using sigaction, then you set a timer using alarm, then make your blocking call.  The blocking call will be interrupted if it does not complete within your chosen timeout (in seconds; if you need finer granularity you can use `setitimer(2)`).

Note that signals in C are somewhat hairy, and there are fairly onerous restriction on what you can do in your signal handler.

This page is useful and fairly concise:
http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-an-Alarm.html

Comment: Thanks!  I think that sounds like what I'd like to have -- but I don't have enough details to understand how to do it yet.  In particular, I don't know how to properly set a signal that will interrupt the blocking call and permanently stop it rather than going back to it once the interrupt handler exits.  Could you add a bit of explanation on how to do that?

Comment: From the GNU link in my answer: "To be able to use the alarm function to interrupt a system call which might block otherwise indefinitely it is important to not set the SA_RESTART flag when registering the signal handler using sigaction."  I'd try that.  Then the question is what the library code does when its primitive operations return EINTR.  If you're lucky, the library you're using will have some sort of "stop" function you can call from your signal handler, or it will just return from the blocking call on EINTR.  If it is more persistent and simply blocks again on EINTR, life is harder.

Comment: Okay, that's starting to make sense -- I'd missed that line, and also hadn't realized that SA_RESTART existed or that anything might happen to the interrupted code other than it continuing where it left off.  Thanks for pointing that out!  (I'm not sure what the library code does in this case, or to what extent we can rely on that since it's got hooks for people to add different code at that level for different communication libraries.  But I'll find out.)

Comment: Accepting this -- I don't think it's actually the answer I want, but if the answer I want existed, I'm pretty sure this would be it.  (I think the actual answer for my particular case is "there is no answer; you can't reliably get there with what you've got.")  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like [select(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29), depending on the OS you are targeting.

Comment: Something like, yes.  That seems to be specific to file descriptors, though, while this is with an arbitrary library call.  It may or may not use file descriptors deep underneath, depending on the version I'm using, but I don't have access to them.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a 'monitor', capable of signaling availability of resource to threads via a shared mutex (typically). In Boost.Thread a [condition_variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [timed locks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html): Your blocking method can aquire the lock before starting to wait and release it as soon as the data is availabe. You can then try to acquire the lock (with a timeout) in your timed wait method.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the blocking call in a separate thread. Have an intermediate message buffer in that thread that is guarded by a condition variable (as said before). Make your main thread timed-wait on that condition variable. Receive the intermediately stored message if the condition is met.

So basically put a new layer capable of timed-wait between the API and your application. Adapter pattern.

Comment: Nice, but then what happens to my separate thread if that blocking call never unblocks?  What if I do this once a minute in a program that runs continuously?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> what happens to that second thread if the blocked call never returns?

I believe there is *nothing* you can do to recover *cleanly* without cooperation from the called function (or library). 'Cleanly' means cleaning up all resources owned by that thread, including memory, other threads, locks, files, locks on files, sockets, GPU resources... *Un*-cleanly, you can indeed kill the runaway thread.